# ipyvuetify user input text field

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, ipywidgets, voila

I am learning the wonderful ipyvuetify widgets environment for rendering nice notebooks with voila.

I am looking for several hours in:
https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Now, already in that link there is no widget for manual user input.

Now observing the material widgets under:
https://material.io/design/introduction

It is possible to see that (of course) there is a lable widget for user entry data.

Does anyone know if (for some reason) ipyvuetify does not offer yet such text user input ?

thanks

NOTE: Other way to formulate this question is simply: What is the equivalent to widgets.Text in ipyvuetify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't `v.TextField(label='Label', placeholder='Placeholder')` provide what you need?

[image]

Comment: I will check. but so far is not listed in the documentation page (that I linked). Checking it straight away

Comment: It doesn't have an list like ipywidgets because there are too many to include. But I think the principle is: Find the widget you want from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/ or any subsection on the left and convert the name following the convention described here: https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify#usage.

Comment: Thats really great. I did the other approach around. I dont have a clue about VUE.

Comment: but when changing the input text the variable is not catched by v.TextField.value. why?

Comment: See here for explanation: https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-the-value

Set `v_model` when creating the widget, and then call it again for the value. `value` only works for assigning.